# Creating custom android service

Tags: android

I am planning to write a service. I am looking at SurfaceFlinger code as reference. SurfaceFlinger derives from both BinderService<> and IInterface<>.

if I want to create a service, is it sufficient to inherit from IInterface and call addService method to add my service to the service manager? Does that allow my application to talk to the new service??

When should we inherit from BinderService??

Comment: `SurfaceFlinger`, `IInterface`, and the service manager are part of the firmware. Unless you are building your own device, or perhaps your own ROM mod, these topics are not relevant for you.

Comment: I have a strong case for creating a system service.

Comment: Then you better have a "strong case" for building your own device, or perhaps your own ROM mod, as you cannot invent a new system service from an app. Note that, on the whole, StackOverflow is better at support app developers than firmware developers. If you do not get help here, you may wish to seek other venues for your questions, such as an appropriate Google Group from the Community page on http://source.android.com.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the directing to proper forum.